# I want to find out word which ends with ()...Use grep

Tags: shell, shell-script, grep

I want to find out word which ends with ()...Using the grep command in linux.

grep file_name_where_i_want_to_search "*()"

some thing like that....but its not working

Comment: "Something like that"? Add the command, including parameters, to your question so we have  a chance of figuring out where you went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat <<EOF > test
foo bar
foo bar() baz
foo.bar() baz
foo bar baz()
foobarbaz() foo bar()baz
EOF
$ grep -o '\w\+()' test
bar()
bar()
baz()
foobarbaz()
bar()
```

- `-o` means "print only matching parts", i.e. not the whole line
- `\w` means "a character within a word"
- `\+` means "the previous entity one or more times"

So, `grep -o '\w\+()'` means "print everything that consists of one or more word characters followed by ()".

This will still match e.g. the `bar()` part of `bar()baz`. One could argue that the parentheses actually end the word, which makes `bar()` "a word that ends in ()". I assume that this is not an issue in your actual use case anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the () like this. if this is in the end of the line you should use regex (egrep)

```
egrep file_name_where_i_want_to_search ".*\(\)$"
```

Comment: grep -rnw 'fuctions_obiee_commonutility.txt' -e "main()"   shows me the correct answer.....as 38:main()

Comment: when i put           grep -rnw 'fuctions_obiee_commonutility.txt' -e ".*\(\)$"  shows no results